# Append React with Redux component into iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React component what use Redux Store. In componentDidMount this component should also add other component into iframe. This iframe is independent not created in component code.

```
<iframe src="empty.html"></iframe>

componentDidMount(){
    let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    let iframeBody = iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
    let el = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('div');
    iframeBody.appendChild(el);
    ReactDOM.render(<ReactRedux.Provider store={store}><SkCanvas /></ReactRedux.Provider>,iframeBody.querySelector('div'));
  }
```

This code don't throw any errors. In new component `SkCanvas` is `console.log` with props and this log is display in my console. Just html code it's visible inside iframe.
Of course if I try add this component to any element outside iframe it works.

Any hint how can I add it there?

It also possible to set this component manually into ifrmae (on init) but I need to share store between this components.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: _This code don't throw any errors. In new component SkCanvas is console.log with props and this log is display in my console. Just html code it's visible inside iframe._ Can you be more precise ? Which components do you want to append ? What is the o/p of console.log ?

Comment: `<SkCanvas />` in append into iframe by other component. In SkCanvas is `console.log(props)` and this log is visible. But html isn't visible inside iframe. 
In general only one thing what I need is use separated css styles for code indise iframe and outside.

Comment: which is the _other component_ ? to which component does this `componentDidMount` belong to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't preserve `context` across `ReactDOM.render()`. So the `store` doesn't get shared between the components outside `iframe` and inside if you use 2 separate `ReactDOM.render()`s.
In general, if you want to render a component inside any HTML element, you can use the following pattern.

Your HTML element:

```
<iframe id='iframe1'></iframe>
```

Then js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const store = configureStore();

class SkCanvas extends Component {
  render() {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}

class FrameApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SkCanvas/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FrameApp/>,
  document.getElementById('iframe1')
);
```

Edit: For rendering React app into and iframe, you can use [react-frame-component](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component). This library ensures the Redux store is available inside the iframe also. See also https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component/issues/29

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your example. I need to render `<FrameApp />` in standard `div`. And just `<SkCanvas />` in iframe. I can make in `FrameApp` `<div><p>some</p><iframe src="/empty.html"><SkCanvas /></iframe></div>` but it doesn't work.

My goal is: use one store what I can by use `<FrameApp />`. Part of nested elements in `FrameApp` should be outside iframe and one `<SkCanvas />` should be inside iframe because I need to separate canvas from css styles what I use for others elements.

Comment: see my updated answer and check if that library solves the problem

Comment: it looks that it works. I need to check does store is updated also in parent component after all to action in iframe but now it works good. Thanks.